# Dependency handling for Android project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble using external libs with a Android project I'm working on. I'm trying to use the Support Library v7 and a couple other libraries. I put the jar files in the 'libs' folder and right clicked on them and clicked `Add Library...`.

The project is compiling fine but when I make and run it a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Offtopic remark: the screenshot of logcat looks great with the Darcula theme, but you could do other users a favor to add the stacktrace as text so it is searchable. Or at least mention the core error **NoClassDefFoundError android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable** in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough to include the jar.

You should import the v7-compat as a library project and when asked for the package name tell IntelliJ to use `android.support.v7.appcompat`. Take care that the manifest looks more or less like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="android.support.v7.appcompat">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <application />
</manifest>
```

After importing the Android-Library project it might be necessary to reload the whole project.

If you still have problems, compare your appcompat-library *.iml file with [this file](https://gist.github.com/hgoebl/8261396)

Comment: Okay, that works for appcompat, but what about other external jars? How do I include Apache IOUtils for instance?

Comment: Other external jars without dependencies on `res/` assets should work like you already used them (just right-click, `Add as Library...`.

Comment: Yes I've done that and everything compiles, but for some reason they are not available at runtime.

Comment: Then you have to go to `File > Project Structure...` and tell IntelliJ to export some of the dependencies. (I thought this is done automatically.) Are you sure your libraries don't have other dependencies? What is the error message / stack-trace?

Comment: Finally got it working, I had to install the rest of Apache's httpcore. Thanks!

Comment: You know that Android already has libraries for Http? You could have a look at [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/). There you can find a list of alternatives. Apache has awesome libraries for Java SE and Java EE, but for Android they often add to much weight to your APK-file. Be sure to use ProGuard to optimize your builds!

Comment: That looks great but doesn't serve all my needs. I'm going to need Cookie management as well as MultipartEntity support but thanks anyways!