# Can't figure how to work with the actionbar. Messed it all up

Tags: android, xml, jar

Here is my problem.
I tried to follow this: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html
I've also tried to use stackoverflow web site, and found many solutions for many similar problems, but nothing helped me!
For some reason I no longer have the "add to path" option in the "v7 appcompat".
I do(!) have the "v7 support appcopat" in the Order and Export.
But I did noticed, in properties > Android > library I have an 'X' symbol in the 'Reference' tab library, and an question mark in the 'Project' tab. What I'm trying to do is to get the Theme.AppCompat.Light. But probably I've got a lot more problems coming because of the v7 jar..
Please, any help!

And by the way, is there any good tutorials you can recommend me please?

Comment: Please check your Console for errors but first clean your project. Afterwards copy and paste the error (if there is any) so we can help you :)

Comment: This is indeed not a simple task and all the examples in the SDK are derived. Even if you're not using Android Studio or IntelliJ, but poor Eclipse, this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927200/) could help you. The most important thing is not to include just the v7-jar, but use the whole v7-appcompat as an Android Library.

Comment: Nop. There is no errors after I clean the project.